# How can I replace/split a dynamic string using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

Suppose i get dynamic string as below.

```
#04215: ["#02080=#04217+#04217_DUP5554","#01066=(#01047+#01111+#01048+#01118+#01049+#01050+#01121+#01128+#01131+#01141+#01138+#01148+#01053+#01062+#01054+#02080+#02048+#01064+#01063+#01065+#01051+#01052+#02062+#02069+#02072+#02079)","#02002=#01066","#02007=(#02002+#02003+#02004+#02005+#02006)","#02010=(#02007+#02008+#02009)","#04216+#04216_DUP5554=#04217+#04217_DUP5554","#04215+#04215_DUP5554=#04216+#04216_DUP5554"]
```

I have to make the part "#04215+#04215_DUP5554=#04216+#04216_DUP5554"] as `"#04215_DUP9262=#04216+#04216_DUP9262"`. I made a regex to match  `'#04215+#04215_DUP9262=' as '([#][0]["+pgNo+"][0-9]{3}[+][#][0]["+pgNo+"][0-9]{3}[_][D][U][P][0-9]{4}[=])'`. I tried the below.

Consider I get dynamic string in variable a;

```
var regex2=new RegExp("([#][0]["+pgNo+"][0-9]{3}[+][#][0]["+pgNo+"][0-9]{3}[_][D][U][P][0-9]{4}[=]) ([#][0]["+pgNo+"][0-9]{3}[_][D][U][P][0-9]{4})" ,"g");

a=a.replace(regex2,'$1,$2');
```

It is not replacing the string.Please help.

The **pgNo** in regex2 is dynamic. In current context, value of it is '4'. Substring is not possible because there are too many '=' symbols. Essentially, I have to change occurence of things like '#04215+#04215_DUP9262=' to '#04215_DUP9262='

Comment: Isn't it possible to substring this on the `=` character?

Comment: Where do you get that string from? Can you change the source? Because, frankly, that is a bad way to exchange information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Try [`.replace(RegExp("(?:[+]?(#" + pgNo + "))+(?=_DUP[0-9]{4}=)","g"), "$1")`](https://regex101.com/r/LYv2lX/1/)

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9xdgjj7e/)

Comment: I don't understand. $1 returns the matched string only. What I need is a replace. Tried all valuable solutions suggested, but none worked.

Comment: Please let me know if $1 can be assigned to a variable for further manipulation ? I am getting matched strings in $1 but not able to do further slicing based on the matching

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this: `/#([0-9]{5})\+#\1/g` => `$1`.

In a code example this would be:

```js
let regex = new RegExp('(#' + pgNo + ')\\+\\1', 'g');
let myString = "#04215+#04215_DUP9262=#04216+#04216_DUP9262";

myString = myString.replace(regex, '$1');
```

In this `(#[0-9]{5})` will match any 5 character number after a hash, `\+` matches the '+' between the numbers, (it has to be escaped otherwise it's interpreted as 'one or more' of the preceding token), and `\1` is a back reference to the first match.

Comment: Please let me know if $1 can be assigned to a variable for further manipulation ? I am getting matched strings in $1 but not able to do further slicing based on the matching

Comment: The `$1` is a reference to the group inside the brackets, so, `(#04215)` would be the capture group here.